# Django and Angular POST request - CSRF failed

Tags: python, django, angularjs, csrf, django-csrf

I have deployed an API with Django REST API Framework in local.
My mobile application is developed with Ionic framework (with AngularJS).

In my app, when I want to request (POST method) in Ajax, I have this error:

> CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect.

I have not received this error when I requested in the Django REST API integrated project.

I researched for solutions on the web, but none of it worked.

Project Information :

Django file **settings.py**:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
'klipix.django-crossdomainxhr-middleware.OrganizationMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
```

I used the TokenAuthentication method (http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication). My **django-crossdomainxhr-middleware.py** file:

```
class OrganizationMiddleware(object):

def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
header_token = request.META.get('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION', None)
if header_token is not None:
  try:
    token = sub('Token ', '', request.META.get('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION', None))
    token_obj = Token.objects.get(key = token)
    request.user = token_obj.user
  except Token.DoesNotExist:
    pass
```

In my app I tried to add this solution but it did not work :

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])
.run(function($rootScope, $ionicPlatform, $http) {

  $http.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
  $http.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider) {

  $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
  $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
  $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
```

Kindly provide valuable inputs for this.

Comment: I am getting the same error . How did you provided csrf token in ionic app from django rest api ?

Comment: the answer by @Jakob Runge is the most accurate , please refer to that....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For me this works with angular 1.4:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []).config(function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken'
    $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken'
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    angular.module('starter', ['ngCookies'])
    .config(function ($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
        $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
    })
   .run( function run( $http, $cookies ){
         $http.defaults.headers.post['X-CSRFToken'] = $cookies['csrftoken'];
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
.run( function run($http, $cookies){
     // For CSRF token compatibility with Django
     $http.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRFToken'] = $cookies['csrftoken'];
});
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me... Can you share with me your Django settings.py file please?

Comment: `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']` And I don't have a custom middleware for that. But I also use REST Framwork with `rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication` in 'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES'. And I don't use `CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL ` and other `CORS` Settings

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your angular $http with django {{csrf_token}}.

Add the follow script into your html after your angular app and controller are imported.

```
<script>
    var app = angular.module('my_app');

    app.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRFToken'] = '{{ csrf_token|escapejs}}';
    }]);
</script>
```